# Mooculus beginner explanation if f(-1) = -7 and f(x) = g(-x*6), what point satisfies?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have been looking at this for awhile and I am having a mental block maybe. The last question of the first section of the Mooculus book is

If $f(-1) = -7$ and $f(x) = g(-6x)$, what point must satisfy g(x)=-7?

I thought the answer was $(1/6, -7)$  but according to the book the answer is $(6, -7)$.

so $f(x) = g(-36)$? How is that right? Can someone give me a hint, maybe I am not thinking of this right. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $f(x) = g(-x \cdot 6)$?.  Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $f\left( -1 \right) =g\left( 6 \right) =-7$

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, N.F. Taussig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=g(-6x)$

$f(-1)=-7$

this means $g(-6\cdot-1)=-7 $ or $ g(6)=-7$

Comment: Ok, thank you, now I see how the answer was arrived at, but I am not sure why we can set $f(x) = g(-6x)$ because the answer is -7 only when x = -1.............. wait, now I get it! I was not substituting the -1 for x in the second equation. I have not done math for years and now I wan't to go back to school. My brain is a little rusty.

Comment: Before wythagoras edited your post you had written $g(-x\cdot6)$ that is the same as $g(-6x)$ I just simplified it as part of the answer. I guess its not an important part of the question so he simplified it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $-7=f(-1)=g((-1)*(-6))=g(6)$

Comment: Now, how do we get the second = sign in your answer? Why can we just set the two equations equal to each other?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now. So simple. Thank you.